# Basic RE in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check whether my string in Java is something like this:

`create table people (name, age, ...);`

I created this regular expression:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("create table [a-zA-Z0-9]+ [([[a-zA-Z0-9]+, ]+)]");
```

But for

```
    String s = "create table tablename (columnname, column) (column)";
    Matcher m = re.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Right");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
```

I always get Right. Can anybody help me, please? I just started to learn RE so I am little lost.

edit. ignore ';' at the end of first line. I am deleting this char inside my program.

Comment: Hint: What do the square brackets in the second half of your expression mean?

Comment: I suppose it is an expression which starts and ends ( and ) between which are a-zA-Z0-9 ended with ', '. Because there is no + after last square bracket it should take only one expressions (x, y, ...), shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square bracket in RE defines a "[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)" (in RE terms not Java class). You have way to many of those. Parentheses (round brackets) are used to [capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) partial matches, which you dont need if you're only interested in the whole string matching the pattern.

For your case I would probably do something like:

```
"^create table \w+ \(\w+(\, \w+)*\)$"
```

where

- `\w+` - non-zero length of "word characters" (letter, digit, or underscore)
- `\(` an `\)` - parentheses matching exactly
- `(\, \w+)*` - zero or more of words separated from previous word by a comma
- `^` and `$` - the beginning and the end of the string

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working a looks very elegant. Spara's answer looks good too but for me (I have already deleted longer whitespaces) is your solution better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is kind of create table sql then it should support whitespaces and non whitespaces like this:

```
create  table  people(name ,   age, addres,phone,mail, ...);
```

So you should use a regex that support valid sql queries, this will helps you:

```
^create\s*table\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*\((?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s*,\s*|\)))+$
```

You can check online [here](https://regex101.com/r/koBfsn/2)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But I already deleted long whitespaces in my program so there will be only one space between two words.